# MongoDB - Using find() to get values in an array

Tags: mongodb

My collection contains documents of the following form:

```
        {
          'game_name': 'football',
          'scores': [4,1,2,7,6,0,5]
        }
```

How do I find the 'scores' of all such objects in the collection and sort them in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your Question

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate([

{
    $unwind:"$scores"
},{

    $sort:{
        "scores":1
        }
},{    
        $group:{
            _id:null,
            scores:{$addToSet:"$scores"}
        }
},{

    $project:{
        _id:0,
        scores:1
    }
}

])
```

Result is:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "scores" : [ 
                7, 
                5, 
                4, 
                6, 
                2, 
                1, 
                0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain $group and $project? I do not know what those are, and $unwind was new for me.

Comment: @Rayu sure ! My english is not perfect but i try to explain

[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) Create document for each element of array

[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is similar Group of My Sql

[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) Reshapes a document, and you can decide witch element do you want see, rename and others function like `$toLower` or `$toUpper` etc...

doc [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)